# How can I extract the data portion of a promise object to pass as props to a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to pass the result of an API call to a component in order to create a dropdown list of data that I have stored in a MySQL database.

The data is fairly static, but I don't want to hardcode it in case the catalog changes in the future.

The problem that I have is that the response from the call to the API returns this structure:

```
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
   data:
      templateTypes: (27) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
[[Prototype]]: Object
status: 200
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I want to be able to pass data.templateTypes as props to the new component, but instead of the templateTypes array I continue to get the Promise Object, and when I try to get data.templateTypes, the console tells me that templateTypes is undefined.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code so far:

AssetsActions.js

```
export async function getAllTemplateTypes() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("/template-types/names");
    const data = response.data;
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return [];
  }
}
```

DropdownList.js

```
import DropdownButton from "react-bootstrap/DropdownButton";
import Dropdown from "react-bootstrap/Dropdown";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import DropdownItems from "./DrowdownItems";
import { getAllTemplateTypes } from "../AssetsActions/AssetsActions";

import styles from "../LeftPanelAssets.module.css";

var optionItemsList = getAllTemplateTypes().then((response) => {
  return response;
});

console.log("Option Items List: ", optionItemsList);

function DropdownList() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const changeValue = (e) => {
    setValue(e);
  };

  return (
    <div id="dropDownContainer">
      <Dropdown>
        <DropdownButton
          variant="outline-primary"
          id="dropdown-basic"
          title="Template Category"
          onSelect={changeValue}
        >
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            <LeftPanelAssetsDropdownItems options={optionItemsList} />
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </DropdownButton>
      </Dropdown>
      <p />
      <Card text className={styles.borderlessTitleFont}>
        Category: {value}
      </Card>
      <p />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DropdownList;
```

DropdownItems.js

```
import ItemElement from "./ItemElement";

function DropdownItems(props) {
  const optionsList = props.options;
  const listItems = optionsList.map((opts) => (
    <ItemElement key={opts.id} data={opts}></ItemElement>
  ));

  return listItems;
}

export default DropdownItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the result in a state variable, otherwise React won't rerender your component when you receive the options.

Like this:

```
import DropdownButton from "react-bootstrap/DropdownButton";
import Dropdown from "react-bootstrap/Dropdown";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import DropdownItems from "./DrowdownItems";
import { getAllTemplateTypes } from "../AssetsActions/AssetsActions";

import styles from "../LeftPanelAssets.module.css";

function DropdownList() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]); // initialize to empty array that will act as placeholder until you get the data

  // This effect will only run on first render
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchOptions() {
      let result = await getAllTemplateTypes();
      setOptions(result);
    }

    fetchOptions();
  }, [])

  const changeValue = (e) => {
    setValue(e);
  };

  return (
    <div id="dropDownContainer">
      <Dropdown>
        <DropdownButton
          variant="outline-primary"
          id="dropdown-basic"
          title="Template Category"
          onSelect={changeValue}
        >
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            <LeftPanelAssetsDropdownItems options={options} />
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </DropdownButton>
      </Dropdown>
      <p />
      <Card text className={styles.borderlessTitleFont}>
        Category: {value}
      </Card>
      <p />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DropdownList;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, just had to do a couple of modifications to get it to work with my dev environment, but for the most part it was just plug and play.

I've been at this all night and now I feel like "Neo" from the Matrix, I can see the code of the simulation... LOL.

I would upvote your answer but I don't have the rep points to do so.

Comment: @Ivan  haha nice to hear. You can accept the answer though :)